# how to receive emails using pop3 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pop3

in my php codeigniter  web application, i want to retrieve emails using pop3. I don't know how to possible?. I am new with php mailer. Anyone can help me. If its not in codeigniter, advice me how is it php.

Answer (score 0):

[IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)

Will help you deal with imap or pop3 emails from your server, its a bit of an undertaking...